# CakePHP: Overrride Controller method with plugin

Tags: cakephp, plugins, controller, overriding

I'm new to this framework and looking to extend/override a Controller method with a plugin. If this is the wrong way to do this please let me know. I just want the solution to be modular in that there is no tampering with the extended controller. This is what I'd like..

```
MyController extends AppController{

function index(){}

}
```

I have a plugin

```
MyPlugin extends MyController{

function index(){}

}
```

I want when MyController->index() gets called it runs MyPlugin->index(). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just run the code from `MyPlugin` inside the `MyController`? Why do you want to override?

Comment: MyContoller may have changes in the future which would overwrite any modifications done to it. This is the reason I want it to be modular.

Comment: We need more concrete examples of these changes overwriting the controller. Maybe there's another solution, because the way I see it, it's a bad design.

Comment: We use a 3rd party application written on CakePHP. We want to modify some of the functionality of the application without modifying any of the core code. This is the reason for making plugins to extend the application without hard-coding anything into the app. If there is an update the core files we modified would be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is some kind of "reverse-inheritance", which is not supported in PHP (one might consider Aspects in Java or ObjectiveC's categories).

As far as I understand, you have the following situation:

```
"3rd Party App's Controller class" extends "CakePHP's Controller class"
```

You get both classes from external upstreams and want to modify the 3rd Party App's Controller without sacrificing either upstream. This is not possible by language, and as far as I can tell CakePHP offers no framework solution.

You might be able to achieve your goal by modifieng the routing, i.e. redirect requests to `MyController` to your custom `MyPlugin` controller and call `MyController`'s action from there.